# non paged pool on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: memory-leaks

I have a problem with Windows Server 2012 R2 for memory leaks (nonpaged pool problem).
I noticed the patches associated with older Windows versions, but not for this version of Windows.
Do you think that changing to Windows 2016 could be a good solution? If you have a better or different solution, please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: I [wrote an answer on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/949246/174557) how to trace this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, because it seems not related to programming. Please see the recommended superuser question.

Comment: thanks  magicandre1981
my network card driver was old version